# Using pywin32 in a GitLab CI YML file - getting error on pip install

Tags: python, pip, gitlab-ci, python-3.8, pywin32

Trying to run a Python program using GitLab's CI pipeline.

I had this running in Teamcity, but I wanted to try in GitLab.

#### First attempt

I supplied an explicit list of `pip install` commands including `wmi`.

```
# This file is a template, and might need editing before it works on your project.
# Official language image. Look for the different tagged releases at:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/library/python/tags/
image: python:3.8.0

# Change pip's cache directory to be inside the project directory since we can
# only cache local items.
variables:
  PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"

# Pip's cache doesn't store the python packages
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching
#
# If you want to also cache the installed packages, you have to install
# them in a virtualenv and cache it as well.
cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/

before_script:
  - python -V  # Print out python version for debugging
  - pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - . venv/bin/activate

test:
  script:
  - python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  - python -m pip install locust
  - locust -V
  - python -m pip install multipledispatch
  - python -m pip install pycryptodome
  - python -m pip install pandas
  - python -m pip install wmi
  - python -m pip install pywin32==300
  - python -m pip install influxdb_client
  - set LOAD_TEST_CONF=load_test.conf
  - locust -f ./src/main.py --host http://x.x.x.x:yyyy -u 1000 -t 1m -r 250 -s 1800 --headless --csv=./LoadTestsData --csv-full-history --html=./LoadTestsReport_VPOS.html  --stream-file ./data/stream_jsons/streams_vpos.json --database=csv
   
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mv ./LoadTests* ../public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
```

[image]

When I ran the program, I got
[image]

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'

#### Second attempt

So I figured I had to explicitly add a line to `pip install pywin32`.

That failed with

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32
```

```
# I tried python:latest, but I used 3.8 successfully in my IDE
image: python:3.8   

variables: ....
cache: ...

test:
  script: 
    - python -V
  - pip install virtualenv
  - virtualenv venv
  - . venv/bin/activate
  - python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  - python -m pip install locust
  - locust -V
  - python -m pip install pywin32==300      #   <----- doesn't like this
  - python -m pip install pypiwin32         #   or this
  - set LOAD_TEST_CONF=load_test.conf
  - locust -f ./src/main.py <a bunch of arguments...>

  ...
```

Results Obtained

```
$ python -m pip install pywin32==300
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==300 (from versions: 302)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==300
```

It shouldn't be an OS mismatch, since the OS of the build environment is Windows, as I see

```
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

I also tried `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`, but the results were the same.

How do I resolve this?

#### Result Using Windows Tag

Zach's answer is getting me on the right track.

I used the exact YAML as in the answer, except with a tag of `win2019`.  I'm not the admin; this is what I found.

I just need to figure out the install problem:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to reproduce it now

Comment: `pywin32` is a Windows-only package. You cannot install it on a Linux runner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the [python:3.8.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/python/library/python/3.8.0/images/sha256-76aace0349933165c34ae8f99b32d269103bc14818c1914b104c34521b92f288?context=explore) image has a windows architecture available, it looks like it's pulling the linux version from that tag.  You can test this by adding the command `uname -srm` to the first line of your test scripts.

I wasn't able to get a windows docker image for python running on a shared runner, but I was able to install python 3.8 on a runner with the following minimal .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
test:
  before_script:
    - Import-Module "$env:ChocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1"
    - choco install python3 --version=$PYTHON_VERSION --yes --force --no-progress
    - refreshenv
  script:
    - python -V
    - python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    - python -m pip install pywin32
  variables:
    PYTHON_VERSION: "3.8"
  tags:
    - windows
```

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I can.  I appreciate the rapid response.

Comment: @Guy I added a small working example

Comment: We are getting closer.  I'll post the result.  I had to get ownership of the project, then I found that there was a win2019 runner and used that.  But there was a problem with the installation of python, it looks like.

Comment: The remaining issues are not germane to this question.   It's all about the tags.